# LibreOffice doesn't work with HUD in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice, hud

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 HUD in LibreOffice stopped to work and it searches in panel indicator instead. After running command `unity --repalce` everything works fine, but it is really annoying to restart unity everytime you start LibreOffice. Is it a bug or can I fix it on my own?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug; I highly recommend you [report it as one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). It should probably be reported against the package `unity` in Ubuntu (rather than against LibreOffice). If you want even more information about bug reporting than provided there, you can see [this question and its answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, I wasn't able to find it since there is not LibreOffice in its name but Writer instead. See [HUD doesn't work with LibreOffice Writer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1061225)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1045353

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the HUD has to learn the menu commands first: running LO for the first time in 12.10, i tried to quit the program using the HUD, but it only showed quit commands for other running apps. I chose "quit" from the menu, re-started LO and voilà: now the HUD knew "quit".

Comment: That is not right. At least not in my case. I can go Format -> Page with mouse, but HUD won't work then either. It's a bug. I would say not well named bug.